# LibGDX static members are not initialized

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX on Android. From one of my LibGDX screens located inside of an Activity (Activity A), I launch a new Activity (Activity B).

I then use `Gdx.files.local()` to read a file. In some instances, Activity B has to be recreated by the Android OS because of memory issues. Unfortunately, the static member `Gdx.files` has not been initialized anymore because it seems that the initialization code only runs inside of a LibGDX activity, therefore causing an Gdx.* access to result in a Null Pointer Exception.

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: Why do you need several activities in the first place?

Comment: Because I use LibGDX inside of an Android application that needs more than one Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply avoided this issue by just `finish`ing Activity B if I detect that the GDX.* members aren't initialized.